# org.apache.jasper.JasperException after deploying project on glassfish4

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, glassfish-4, facesservlet

after deploying my JSP application on glassfish4 on Eclipse 4.16.0 (using jdk1.8.0_251) and publish it locally the server response is that:
[jasper exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i11lC.png)

my web.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/jsp"     xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.4">
  <display-name>mydocuweb</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

my faces-config.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE faces-config PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JavaServer Faces Config 1.1//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-facesconfig_1_1.dtd">

<faces-config>

<application>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>en_US</default-locale>
    </locale-config>
    <message-bundle>jsfdb.view.res.Messages</message-bundle>
</application>

<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>loginInfo</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>jsfdb.view.LoginInfoBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>

<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>subscriber</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>jsfdb.view.SubscriberBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>email</property-name>
        <null-value/>
    </managed-property>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>password</property-name>
        <null-value/>
    </managed-property>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>name</property-name>
        <null-value/>
    </managed-property>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>manager</property-name>
        <value>true</value>
    </managed-property>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>developer</property-name>
        <value>true</value>
    </managed-property>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>administrator</property-name>
        <value>true</value>
    </managed-property>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>subscriptionType</property-name>
        <value>1</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>

<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/subscribe.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>subscribed</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/subscribed.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>

<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/login.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>profile</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/profile.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>list</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/list.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>

<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/profile.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>login</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/login.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>

<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/unsubscribe.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>login</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/login.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>unsubscribed</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/unsubscribed.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>cancel</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/profile.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

the file that i would to connect is login.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" %>
<!--  -->
<c:remove var="subscriber" scope="session"/>

<f:view>

<f:loadBundle var="labels" basename="jsfdb.view.res.Labels"/>
<c:set var="stylesheet"
    value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/stylesheet.css"/>

<html>
<head>
    <title><h:outputText value="#{labels.login}"/></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="<c:out value='${stylesheet}'/>">
</head>
<body>
<h1><h:outputText value="#{labels.login}"/></h1>

<h:outputLink value="subscribe.faces">
    <h:outputText value="#{labels.subscribe}"/>
</h:outputLink>

<h:form id="login">

    <h:messages globalOnly="true" styleClass="message"/>

    <p><h:outputLabel for="email"
        value="#{labels.email}"/>
    <h:message for="email" styleClass="message"/><br>
    <h:inputText id="email" required="true"
            value="#{loginInfo.email}"
            size="40" maxlength="80">
        <f:validateLength minimum="1" maximum="80"/>
    </h:inputText>

    <p><h:outputLabel for="password"
        value="#{labels.password}"/>
    <h:message for="password" styleClass="message"/><br>
    <h:inputSecret id="password" required="true"
            value="#{loginInfo.password}"
            size="10" maxlength="20">
        <f:validateLength minimum="6" maximum="20"/>
    </h:inputSecret>

    <p><h:commandButton id="command"
        value="#{labels.login}"
        action="#{loginInfo.loginAction}"/>

</h:form>
</body>
</html>
</f:view>
```

finally the error is

```
[2020-07-15T11:37:03.696+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=27             
_ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1594805823696] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[FacesServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet FacesServlet threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /pages/login.jsp(12,0) PWC6236: According to TLD or attribute             directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:81)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:376)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:204)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.checkXmlAttributes(Validator.java:1190)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:859)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1502)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2297)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2347)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:879)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1502)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2297)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2347)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:499)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2297)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validate(Validator.java:1890)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:223)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:451)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:643)
    at     com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:153)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:792)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:48)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:153)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]
```

copied from server.log.

anyone has an idea? the scope of this application is to create a simple login webapp using jsp/jsf that connect with a database mysql. for the moment i did not provide the connection to the db, but i wish to verify the correct implementation of java and jsp implementation.

thanks to all

Comment: Is this is new app? With JSF 1.1? That is over 15 year old technology. Start with reading https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: no, the version of JSF is 2.3 but i've to learn that because i have to fix an application wrote on 2012. this afternoon i tried to resolve and i think this is a TLD problem

Comment: Using jsp and a 1.1 faces-config on jsf 2.3 is not something you should try. Use jsf 1.2 (at most). But wheter that runs on glassfish 4.1 I'm not sure.

Comment: i'll follow your advice. but when i start writing this app with these features and i've wrote only hello.jsp it worked. i think it's not a version trouble

Answer (score 0):

[RESOLVED]

i find a solution:

replace the line of login.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
```

with

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

and it works!